# Is it possible to have a search path for subfiles?

Tags: paths, subfiles

Similar to how the `graphicspath` works, would it be possible to create a search path `subfilespath` for .tex files instead of images?

For example, given a folder structure as below.

```
- Main
   - FolderA
      - subfileA.tex
      - subfileB.tex
   - FolderB
      - FolderC
         - subfileC.tex
      - subfileA.tex
   - main.tex
```

I imagine the following document structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\subfilespath{
    {FolderA}
    {FolderB}
}
\begin{document}
\subfiles{subfileA.tex} % Found in FolderA, not FolderB, because FolderA is first in search path
\subfiles{subfileB.tex} % Found in FolderA
\subfiles{subfileC.tex} % Found recursively via FolderB in FolderC
\end{document}
```

## Edit

I should mention that I'm setting up a folder structure for software manuals, where one software can overlap with another, therefore I want to be able to re-use certain subfiles in multiple documents. Per manual, I want to indicate a set of dependent paths, where each path points to a folder that contains a bunch of subfiles, organized in subdirectories. I figured it would make my life easier to have a way to have a dynamic search path for subfiles, so I can add subdirectories without having to add them to the search path.

Comment: The good news is `\IfFileExists`.  The bad news is that there is no way to generate a list of file names given the folder name.

Comment: latex has `\input@path` which is a list of `{..}` directories to search for input  files. `\graphicspath` is just an afterthought a quick trick to locally redefine  `\input@path` to a list specific to graphics, so `\input@path`  is probably what you want

Comment: If you use the l3 stuff to input your files, you can easily add search paths in the document (and they do not need to be sub-directories). I use this a lot in teaching materials, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of @DavidCarlisle I came up with the solution below. Feel free to shoot holes in my solution.

I should also mention that I'd like to keep `\dependentPaths` comma-separated because I use it in other places to loop over the items in the list.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{subfiles}

% Define file name
\newcommand{\fileName}{searchpath.txt}

% List of directories
% Can be a comma-separated list of directories to include in search path
\newcommand{\dependentPaths}{.}

% Replace commas by apostrophes to create list of paths in command prompt
\StrSubstitute{"\dependentPaths"}{,}{" "}[\maindirs]

\makeatletter

% Print files
\immediate\write18{dir \maindirs /s /b /ad > \fileName}

% Command to add to input path
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\newcommand{\appendInputPath}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\input@path{#1}%
}

% Read file and add lines to input path
\newread\myread
\openin\myread=\fileName
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1
\loop\unless\ifeof\myread
    \readline\myread to \line
    \expandafter\appendInputPath\expandafter{\expandafter{\line}}
\repeat
\endgroup
\closein\myread

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Load subfiles using search path:\\
\subfile{subfileA.tex}
\subfile{subfileB.tex}
\subfile{subfileC.tex}

\end{document}
```

The content of `searchpath.txt` is as below.

```
C:\Users\<path to main>\FolderA
C:\Users\<path to main>\FolderB
C:\Users\<path to main>\FolderB\FolderC
```

Within the subfiles, I wrote the location of the file so I can see which subfiles are loaded. The PDF shows the following:

[image: what does this do?]

Comment: From you example, it is not clear what you are using the `subfiles` package for, and what you intentions are. In order to typeset `main.tex` and find the correct files, it is sufficient to include `\makeatletter\def\input@path{{FolderA}{FolderB}{FolderB/FolderC}}\makeatother` in the preamble of `main.tex`.

Comment: There are only a few use cases where the `subfiles` package may help. A crucial requirement is that you want to be able to typeset each `subfileX` on its own (sitting in its folder). If this is the case, and if you want e.g. that `subfileC` includes `subfileA` (in `FolderA`), then specify a corresponding `\input@path` in the preamble of `subfileC`. The philosophy of the `subfiles` package is that the path information should make sense relative to the file currently typeset (here `subfileC`).

Comment: @gernot I added an edit to the question regarding my intensions for the subfiles. As mentioned in my answer, I'd like to define the list of dependent paths in one place, which will be used in more places than just for defining the input path. Also, this way allows me to create more and more subdirectories without the need to add them to the input path.

Comment: @gernot regarding your second comment; I believe you're indicating that this might cause issues when `searchpath.txt` is created when e.g. `subfileA.tex` is compiled, which I understand. In this case, I could play with `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded`, making things a little complicated but still feasible. The intention is that `subfileA` will only load subfiles located in subdirectories of `FolderA`.

Comment: Take a look at the [`import` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf). It contains only the logic regarding finding files relative to some included file, but does not implement anything like skipping preambles of included files (because it assumes that the sub-files are not files to be typeset on their own, but just shared between several master documents). Internally, the `subfiles` package uses `import`. The idea would be to set `\input@path` in the preamble of the respective main document, and then use `\import` to load common sub-documents.

Comment: Instead of reading an input path that is common to several master documents from a file, you may as well put `\input@path{{FolderA}{FolderB}...}` into this file and then use `\usepackage{this_file}` in the preamble of the master documents do load it. This does not require extra machinery that might break.

Comment: Initializing `\input@path` in the main preamble with some directories is fine, but trying to modify it dynamically within subfiles will probably cause headache, as the `\import`/`\subfile` commands also append directories to `\input@path`, but without adapting other relative pathes in the list to point to the right place from a different position in the document tree.

Comment: @gernot I'll check out the `import` package, but I would still like to be able to compile subfiles by themselves, unless using `\import` instead of `\subfile` makes compilation time faster. Already during some testing I run into lots of troubles with relative paths in subfiles, so I might indeed migrate to the `import` package. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: The general approach is correct. First, look for the files. When found, set variables equal to the found paths. Then use those variables for `subfiles`. The other way around, making `subfiles` do the search, is not part of that package. Incidentally, I use `subfiles`. Great! Better than `import` (although it invokes `import`). Tip: Unless they are in a standard TeX location automatically found by kpathsea, be sure to keep your subfiles (and images, etc.) in the same folder as, or a subfolder relative to, your main document. They you can copy/move all together.